# Oracle CRM On Demand, Client Side Extensions

Tags: oracle, crm, client-side-scripting, ondemand

After lurking for a long time, I finally have a question I can't google my way out of.

I am working for an Oracle CRM On Demand implementation to use client side extensions to enhance some functionality for our Clients.

At the moment the most pressing issue is the fact that when I am pinging an object, let's say an Activity, I get some but not all of its attributes.

For example, '/OnDemand/....../Activity/1234-56789A' ends up returning the Id of the Activity and the two urls.  There is so much more content though, that I need to find.  I could spend the next day going through every single attribute, throwing it on the end of a '?fields=SomeThing,OrAnother' string, but that seems like massive over kill.

Is there any one who knows how to do this?

All my thanks,
Riye.